# PopUp alert box for Mandatory field checking and Asterisk symbol near label - JSP Form Spring mvc

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp

I need Asterisk symbol to indicate a required input near form control label and make popup alert for mandatory field if it is not filled up

```
 <div class="form-group form-group">
            <label for="status" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                <spring:message code="labels.status"/>
            </label>

            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input id="picture" class="form-control" type="text" value="${form.status}" name="status"
                       autofocus/>
                <form:errors path="status" style="color:red;"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag JavaScript?

Comment: yes  I would like to do that in javascript.

Comment: Do what? "I need * symbol" is not really a question. Please may you make your question clearer so we can help?

Comment: May you remove this comment?

Comment: what you can do is use jquery to perform validation and dom manipulation for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below code in css file.

```
.required:after {
content:" *";
color: red;
```

}

Added required in label class.

```
<label for="status" class="col-sm-2 control-label required ">
            <spring:message code="labels.status"/>
```